# Using seamless R in Rcpp function

Tags: rcpp

I thought I have seen before that you can write a Rcpp function and use R code inside of it. I just can't find the link anymore and using google doesn't help at all. Can you provide me an example or a link where it will be explained how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the `/*** R ... */` expression at the bottom, see the 'Rcpp Attributes' vignette.

So for the code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void reallyWorks() {
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Oh, wow, it works" << std::endl;
}

/*** R
reallyWorks()
*/
```

we get the expected behaviour straight from `sourceCpp()`:

```
> sourceCpp("/tmp/soQ.cpp")

> reallyWorks()
Oh, wow, it works
>
```

Comment: Perfect! This works like intended. A quick question besides: is it possible to write a Rcpp function wich returns a R data structure?

Comment: Of course.That is the _whole point_ of using `SEXP`.  But please read _at least_ the Rcpp Introduction vignette from beginning to end now, rather than asking loads of somewhat beginner-ish questions here.

Comment: And again, thanks for accepting, an up vote would be nice too.

Comment: Thank you Sir.  This one hit me right before leaving for work and writing the answer "felt" quicker than looking for dupes.  There must be some, at least _implicitly_.